# sessions before September 2021 changed to zero

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've been getting monthly access data(users, sessions, pageviews) for a GA4 property by using Google Analytics Data API beta.

Yesterday, I got data with zero sessions before September 2021.
When I get data for the same site in December, there were 400-1000 sessions per month for the same period.
In Google Analytics screen, I also cannot see sessions before August 2021 right now.
I confirmed that it happened in several GA4 properties.

Is it outage or expected behavior or change of api?

My api call spec:
metrics='screenPageViews', 'sessions', 'totalUsers', 'userEngagementDuration', 'engagementRate'
dimensions='year', 'month'

Using googleapis/php-analytics-data v0.8.2.
Althought it's not the latest version, but it seems no related diffs with the latest version: https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data/compare/v0.8.2...v0.8.4